# How to calculate the setting for BCLK with Core i7?

Tags: cpu, overclocking, intel-core-i7

Help me figure out the proper calculation for overclocking a Core i7.

Given that:

- the default maximum memory speed is 1333MHz,
- the motherboard supports up to 2200 MHz by overclocking, and
- it has a 2x memory multiplier as for Core i7 CPUs,

How do you calculate what setting BCLK should be for 1600 MHz and 2133 MHz?

Comment: 1600mhz i7? What i7 is this? Unless you mean memory is 1600 mhz/2133mhz? Be a little more specific, and I would be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look into the frequency-clock structure of i3/5/7 systems:

First you have BCLK, which stands for base clock.
And then you have the multiplier (for CPU).
And then you have the multiplier (for ram).

Then, if you are using a i7-860, then the default setting would be below:

- BCLK = 133
- Multiplier = 21
- RAM multiplier = 10

which results in a cpu frequency of 2.8GHz and ram frequency of 1333MHz.

For example, if you are using ram rated at 1600MHz & You want to achieve a 4GHz clock, then you need to set the following...

- BCLK = 200
- Multiplier = 20
- RAM multiplier = 8

which gives you the above frequencies...